# Issues changing DEFAULT for a datetimeoffset column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datetimeoffset column that currently has a default of

```
(CONVERT([datetime],(0),(0)))
```

I'm trying to change it so the default is

> (CONVERT([datetime],(0)))

When I drop/add the default constraint to get the second one, the default goes to the first one. I assumed at first that the second one just changes to the first because they're equal, but upon creation of the DB I get the first one when I look up the default. Any ideas why this would be happening, or how to fix it?

Comment: This is the way SQL Server will store your calculation internally. Does it change the way the value is calculated? No. Should you concern yourself with it? No.

Answer (score 1):

The way the data is storing shouldn't be an issue, aaron is right.  SQl can use CONVERT() function easily and fix this for you when pulling it.
It is best to actually convert the datetime in what ever application you wish to show it though in my opinion.